# Button not wrapping content inside Box in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Why is it every time I add an icon to a button, the button's width seems to stretch to the screen's edges rather than wrap to its contents?

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.VerticalAlignTop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(18.dp),
            contentDescription = "drawable_icons",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
    }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.back_to_top),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    )
}
```

[image]

**FunnySaltyFish's suggestion**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furthermore, if you want to write a Button, I suggest you use the `Button` Composable directly. It provides support for accessibility mode.

```kotlin
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp),
        onClick = { }
    ) {
        // all the content below will be wrapped in a Row
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(18.dp),
            contentDescription = "drawable_icons",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Text("Back To Top")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you set `fillMaxWidth` to your `Row`, so it will fill the space.

```kotlin
Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth() // remove this line
            .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
    )
```

Just remove it.

Comment: Almost, but now the icon is hiding behind the text. See latest screenshot in my question.

Comment: That is because you put `Text` outside the  `Row`. Chaning it to `Row { Icon() \n Spacer() \n Text() }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Text()` and `Row()` both are insid composable function `Box()`

Wrap your `Text()` Inside `Row()` instead of `Box()`

**From**

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.VerticalAlignTop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(18.dp),
            contentDescription = "drawable_icons",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
    } // Here is little mistake we need to put this after text
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.back_to_top),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    )
}
```

**To**

```
   Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.ExitToApp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(18.dp),
                contentDescription = "drawable_icons",
                tint = Color.Unspecified
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp)) // For Spacing 5 dp

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier,
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.challenges),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            )
        }
        
    }
```